# Mono 2.10.12 VB.Net compiler not found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, mono, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have installed Xamarin Studio and Mono 2.10.11 on my mac, then i have started a new project ASP.NET VB, and when i started that a popup was showed about an update to mono 2.10.12, i installed it but first time i was getting an error and 2. time it was installed.

When i run my first page a Hello World, i get a Visual Basic .Net compiler not found (mono 2.10.12) TestPage, if i look in project (Xamarin) i can see that it use Mono 2.10.12 under Activ Runtime.

But its showing it like
Mono 2.10.12
Mono 2.10.11 (/libery/...........)

There is no libery line after 2.10.12 when i look in my libery/frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions i have both 2.10.11 and 2.10.12 folder.

Why do i get the compiler not found error !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but mono-basic is missing in the package 2.10.11. I think it's a bug and no one at Xamarin noticed it, because they are all using C#. ;(

Download Mono 2.10.9 from http://mono-project.com/OldReleases